# Find minimal value $ \sqrt {{x}^{2}-5\,x+25}+\sqrt {{x}^{2}-12\,\sqrt {3}x+144}$ without derivatives.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, radicals

Find minimal value  of $ \sqrt {{x}^{2}-5\,x+25}+\sqrt {{x}^{2}-12\,\sqrt {3}x+144}$ without using the derivatives and   without the formula for the distance between  two points.
By using the derivatives I have  found  that the minimal value  is $13$  at $$ x=\frac{40}{23}(12-5\sqrt{3}).$$

Comment: Completion of squares, followed by AM-GM may work.

Comment: Why not the formula for the distance between two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the expression in question, $f(x) = \sqrt {{x}^{2}-5\,x+25}+\sqrt {{x}^{2}-12\,\sqrt {3}x+144}$, can be written as follows:

$$
f(x) = \sqrt {(a(x))^2 + (b(x))^2}+\sqrt {(a(x))^2 + (13 - b(x))^2}
$$ 
where 
$$a(x) =\frac{x (- 5\sqrt3 - 12) + 120}{26}  $$
$$b(x) =\frac{x (12\sqrt3 -5) + 50}{26}  $$
Now from $(a(x))^2 \ge 0$ follows
$$
f(x) \ge \sqrt {(b(x))^2}+\sqrt { (13 - b(x))^2} = 13
$$
but also, for $a(x) = 0$ we have $f(x) = 13$. So indeed $13$ is the smallest value that $f(x)$  can attain. Again, this value is  reached for $a(x) = 0$, i.e. $x = \frac{120}{5\sqrt3 + 12} = \frac{40}{23}(12-5\sqrt{3})$ as already given by the OP. This completes the proof.

I can give a general construction method of how to arrive at the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. $\quad \Box$

Comment: Not only a general construction of how to arrive to $\;a(x),\,b(x)\;$ could be in place here, but also how did you think of evaluating $\;\sqrt{13-b(x)^2}\;$ **without knowing first that the minimal value is** $\;13\;$ ?

Comment: Well, the question was to find the minimum without using derivatives and without using distance formulas. That doesn't forbid to get some knowledge about the minimum first (e.g. from  derivatives or distance formulas) and then use that knowledge to construct the required proof. That technique is often observed in inequality proofs, which admittedly look elegant but mysterious if the author doesn't reveal where his "13" came from. Here, as several comments above have already pointed out, the focus certainly was NOT on deriving the value 13.

Comment: The general case  is discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968062).

Answer (score 3):

If we complete the squares we get $$\sqrt{\left(x-{5\over 2}\right)^2 +{75\over 4}} + \sqrt{ (x-6\sqrt{3})^2 +36}.$$  This is the distance from the point $P(x,0)$ to the point $Q(5/2, -5\sqrt{3}/2)$ plus the distance from $P(x,0)$ to the point $R(6\sqrt{3},6).$  Choosing $x$ amounts to sliding $P$ along the $x$-axis.  The shortest sum of distances will be the straight line segment from $Q$ to $R$.  This length is $$\sqrt{ \left( 6+{5\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^2 +(6\sqrt{3}-5/2)^2}=13.$$

Comment: Thank you,  but I know the solution, I asked for a solution without the  distance formula/

Comment: I saw the "no derivatives" bit, but missed the "no distance formula."  $(5,12,13)$ is a famous Pythagorean triple, and you got $5^2$ and $12^2$ in the problem, along with the answer being $13^2$, so good luck avoiding Pythagorean Theorem in the problem.

Comment: +1. I find your answer is quite fine. It's quite weird: Find distance $\underline{without}$ distance formula. We should propose the tag 'without' !!!. It's becoming too popular in MSE.