# Minimal value of $\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + b^2} +\sqrt{(x-c)^2 + d^2}$ without derivatives and without distance formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, radicals

Let  $f(x) = \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + b^2} +\sqrt{(x-c)^2 + d^2}$, where all coefficients are real.

It can be shown using a distance formula that the minimal value of $f(x)$ is 
$D = \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(|b|+|d|)^2}$.

Show that result without derivatives and without a distance formula. At what value of $x$ does the minimum of $f(x)$ occur?

Hint: this is a generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967129/).

Comment: [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: Minkowski's inequality works but it is essentially an inequality on a distance measure.  Can you do without?

Comment: It's hard to say, since different people have different opinion on whether the inequality involves distance formula. For example, is Cauchy-Schwarz an inequality about distance? But Minkowski's inequality may be considered as a direct consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, w.l.o.g., $b > 0$ and $d > 0$.

Define

$$
x_0 = \frac{ad+bc}{b+d}
$$

Further, as already stated in the question, the minimum value of $f$ is
$D = \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b+d)^2}$.

The following equality holds

$$
f(x) = \sqrt {(g(x))^2 + (h(x))^2}+\sqrt {(g(x))^2 + (D - h(x))^2}
$$ 
where 
$$g(x) = \frac{b+d}{D} \; (x-x_0) $$
and
$$h(x) =\frac{1}{D} \; \Big[(c-a)\, x + a^2 - c a + b^2 + d b\Big] $$

Now from $(g(x))^2 \ge 0$ follows
$$
f(x) \ge \sqrt {(h(x))^2}+\sqrt { (D - h(x))^2} = D
$$
with equality for $g(x) =0$ which corresponds to $x=x_0$. So indeed $D$ is the smallest value that $f(x)$  can attain, and this happens at $x=x_0$. This completes the proof without distance measures and without derivatives.  $\quad \Box$

If required, the formulae can be re-interpreted geometrically. Note that $f(x)$ is the sum of the distances from point $N = (x,0)$ to the points $P_1 = (a,b)$ and $ P_2 = (c,-d)$. Consider the line $P_1 P_2$. From a distance argument, the minimum of $f(x)$ is  the length of $P_1 P_2$ which is $D$.

Define a point $R$ on that line $P_1 P_2$  such that $NR$ is perpendicular to  $P_1 P_2$. Then $g(x)$ is the length of  $NR$,  $h(x)$ is the length of  $P_1R$, and $D-h(x)$ is the length of  $P_2R$. Since $NR$ is perpendicular to  $P_1 P_2$, the two square roots  then calculate the distances $NP_1$ and $NP_2$ in a Pythagorean way. The minimum of $f(x)$ is obtained for $N = R$, i.e. $g(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Applying Fermat's Principle on reflection:**

Assume $a<c$,

\begin{align*}
  T(x) &= \sqrt{(x-a)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+d^2} \\
  T'(x) &=\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+b^2}}-\frac{c-x}{\sqrt{(x-c)^2+d^2}} \\
  0 &= \sin i-\sin r \\
  i &= r \\
\end{align*}

> If you've accepted the law of reflection, then
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \frac{x-a}{b} &= \frac{c-x}{d} \\
>     x &= \frac{ad+bc}{b+d}
>   \end{align*}
>
> where $b,d>0$

See [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937158/minimum-value-of-fracx-a2-p-frac-12v-1-frac-x-b2-q/1937432#1937432) for the case of refraction.

Comment: Fermat's principle calls for the shortest path. "Shortest" means derivatives --> that's fine, but it was asked for a method without derivatives.

Comment: It can be pure geometrical problem if we assign the points $(a,|b|)$ and $(c,-|d|)$, then the shortest path is a straight line.  By the way, it's hardly to have **no correlation with distance** if the function $f(x)$ has some sort of metric behaviours.

Comment: Please follow the hint in the question which is a special case. There, people have expressed the same opinion. I have given an answer there which avoids distances and derivatives.

Comment: If you require the readers follow what you've answered another question, it's just duplication of another question.  Do you want to give challenge to the readers or really want to ask a new question?

Comment: Fine if you can generalize the arguments that I have given for the special case. Also fine if you come up with new ideas.

Comment: @Andreas: "Shortest" means "shortest", and not "derivative". It's only the freshman's everlasting chant: "If you hear min you have to differentiate".

Comment: In the second line of NgChungTak's answer there is a derivative $T'(x)$, is it?